# ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host) when changing the wifi network using ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When using my app on ics, after I change my wifi network from networkA to networkB  all the requests for images start coming back with an exception.

failed with exception

```
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
> https://m1.testapp.com refused    at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   at
> com.testApp.android.ws.PooledRequestProcessor$Runner.run(PooledRequestProcessor.java:298)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)  Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /109.233.153.38 (port
> 443) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to
> host)     at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
>   ... 10 more  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: failed to connect
> to /109.233.153.38 (port 443) after 20000ms: isConnected failed:
> EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)   at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:220)    at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:152)   at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)    at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)    at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)    at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)      at
> org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>   ... 10 more  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected
> failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)   at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:201)
```

The strangest thing is that even uninstalling the app and reinstalling it wont fix it, just turning the phone off and on.

I saw a similar problem here http://groups.google.com/group/newsrob/browse_thread/thread/ea2f26d9d1753b79/5800e268eeab399c#5800e268eeab399c . The problem is not happening on phones with 4.0.3, just on the ones with 4.0.1, and the update doesnt seem to be available in Europe yet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's taking a while for the switch over to take place for some reason?  You can check to see if there is an active network connection before making the request:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo                 = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() && networkInfo.isAvailable())
{
    // DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO ON THE NETWORK
}
else
{
    // PROMPT USER THAT NETWORK IS DISCONNECTED

        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no active network connection!", 5000).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While switching and establishing with new network device may take some time. The below code may help you.

```
ConnectivityManager connMngr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try {
    return connMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problem with TCP protocol. It maybe in case weak WiFi or 3G signal. Use try/catch for it.

Answer (score 0):

> failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

So the routing has not been set up correctly.

I found that for some devices you have to set the `WifiConfiguration`’s `ipAssignment` field to `WifiConfiguration.IpAssignment.DHCP` manually for that a DHCP request is performed after changing the wifi programatically. This can only be done via reflection, [see this answer how to code it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968182/1503237). Catch all exceptions, because on other devices the field does not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this is how I solved it.

1. Disable your firewalls
2. go to your server folder (in my case I was using Node.js) the WWW file and listen on the provided port, on all network interfaces.

   **server.listen(port, ip);**

   ```
    server.on('error', onError);
    server.on('listening', onListening);
   ```
3. Make sure the IP address is your local network IP, on widows this can be gotten by typing **ipconfig** on command prompt.
4. restart the server and try connecting again.