# how to change wifi advanced option from code that chrome lost access to internet

Tags: android, proxy, wifi

**this is my situation** : I have an android device that is **not root**. this device connected to a wifi modem that has internet access,

[image]

so the device has internet access and chrome can open websites.

[image]

I want to change **IP Setting** or **Proxy setting** for this connection

[image][image]

from code that chrome could not open websites anymore. I **don't** want to : **disconnect or go to airplane mode or reconnect**. I used code like this "**[sample code that change ip setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303151/changed-wifi-advanced-option-from-code-but-it-wont-work)**" and it change ip setting but chrome still open websites.
how can I achieve this purpose ?? Its long time I stock in this task and I try all answers in web but they didn't work.I appreciate any help friends

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked if the IP settings has been applied correctly after changing them programmatically? If you have a possibility to trace the requests for instance with wireshark, you will see if the requests are still send from the old IP address. I was wondering, why you don't want to reconnect? Maybe there is another solution, which does fit more to your question.

Comment: @DenisLoh according to his linked question the settings weren't updated. It looks like there is a conflict when duplicating a hotspot setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to linked code which i have answered there is hard-coded network id so all the efforts of ip and dns setting wont get applied .

Below is my complete modified code of proxy setting :
[Note : please do check hard-coded things and change it accordingly]

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new aynctask().execute();

    }

    public class aynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            connectToAP("MyWifi", "qwer!@#$");

            WifiConfiguration wifiConf = null;
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager
                    .getConfiguredNetworks();
            for (WifiConfiguration conf : configuredNetworks) {
                Log.d(TAG, "conf.networkId == 1" + (conf.networkId == 9));
                Log.d(TAG, "   conf.networkId == " + conf.networkId);
                Log.d(TAG, "    conf.bbid == " + conf.BSSID);
                Log.d(TAG, "    conf.ssid == " + conf.SSID);
                String BACKSLASH = "\"";
                if (conf.SSID.equals(BACKSLASH + "MyWifi" + BACKSLASH)) {
                    // if (conf.SSID.equals("12345")) {
                    wifiConf = conf;
                    setWifiProxySettings(wifiConf);
                    try {
                        setIpAssignment("STATIC", wifiConf); // or "DHCP" for
                                                             // dynamic setting
                        setIpAddress(InetAddress.getByName("155.128.0.100"),
                                24, wifiConf);
                        setGateway(InetAddress.getByName("8.2.4.2"), wifiConf);
                        // setDNS(InetAddress.getByName("4.3.4.3"), wifiConf);
                        wifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConf); // apply the
                                                             // setting
                        wifiManager.saveConfiguration(); // Save it

                        wifiManager.disconnect();
                        wifiManager.reconnect();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void setIpAssignment(String assign, WifiConfiguration wifiConf)
            throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
            NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        setEnumField(wifiConf, assign, "ipAssignment");
    }

    public static void setEnumField(Object obj, String value, String name)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field f = obj.getClass().getField(name);
        f.set(obj, Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) f.getType(), value));
    }

    public static void setIpAddress(InetAddress addr, int prefixLength,
            WifiConfiguration wifiConf) throws SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException,
            ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        Object linkProperties = getField(wifiConf, "linkProperties");
        if (linkProperties == null)
            return;
        Class laClass = Class.forName("android.net.LinkAddress");
        Constructor laConstructor = laClass.getConstructor(new Class[] {
                InetAddress.class, int.class });
        Object linkAddress = laConstructor.newInstance(addr, prefixLength);

        ArrayList mLinkAddresses = (ArrayList) getDeclaredField(linkProperties,
                "mLinkAddresses");
        mLinkAddresses.clear();
        mLinkAddresses.add(linkAddress);

    }

    public static void setGateway(InetAddress gateway,
            WifiConfiguration wifiConf) throws SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException,
            NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        Object linkProperties = getField(wifiConf, "linkProperties");
        if (linkProperties == null)
            return;
        Class routeInfoClass = Class.forName("android.net.RouteInfo");
        Constructor routeInfoConstructor = routeInfoClass
                .getConstructor(new Class[] { InetAddress.class });
        Object routeInfo = routeInfoConstructor.newInstance(gateway);

        ArrayList mRoutes = (ArrayList) getDeclaredField(linkProperties,
                "mRoutes");
        mRoutes.clear();
        mRoutes.add(routeInfo);
    }

    public static void setDNS(InetAddress dns, WifiConfiguration wifiConf)
            throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
            NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object linkProperties = getField(wifiConf, "linkProperties");
        if (linkProperties == null)
            return;

        ArrayList<InetAddress> mDnses = (ArrayList<InetAddress>) getDeclaredField(
                linkProperties, "mDnses");
        mDnses.clear(); // or add a new dns address , here I just want to
                        // replace DNS1
        mDnses.add(dns);
    }

    public static Object getField(Object obj, String name)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field f = obj.getClass().getField(name);
        Object out = f.get(obj);
        return out;
    }

    public static Object getDeclaredField(Object obj, String name)
            throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object out = f.get(obj);
        return out;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    String TAG = "wifi";
    WifiManager wifiManager;

    public void connectToAP(String ssid, String passkey) {
        String BACKSLASH = "\"";
        String NETWROK_SECURITY_WEP = "WEP";
        String NETWROK_SECURITY_NONE = "NONE";
        String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA = "WPA";
        String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA2 = "WPA2";
        String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2 = "WPA/WPA2 PSK";
        String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_TKIP = "TKIP";
        String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_AES = "AES";
        String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_WEP = "WEP";
        String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_NONE = "NONE";
        int FAILED_TO_ADD_NETWORK = -1;

        Log.d(TAG, "Inside addWifiConfig...");
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        String wifiName = ssid;
        conf.SSID = BACKSLASH + wifiName + BACKSLASH;
        String securityType = NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2;
        Log.d(TAG, "Security Type :: " + securityType);
        if (NETWROK_SECURITY_WEP.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
            conf.wepKeys[0] = passkey;
            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        } else if (NETWROK_SECURITY_NONE.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        } else if (NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)
                || NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA2.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)
                || NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
            conf.preSharedKey = BACKSLASH + passkey + BACKSLASH;
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers
                    .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers
                    .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        }
        // TODO need to cheak if security detail is needed
        String wlanAdditionalSecurity = "";
        if (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_TKIP
                .equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers
                    .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        } else if (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_AES
                .equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers
                    .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        } else if (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_WEP
                .equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        } else if (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_NONE
                .equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers
                    .set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.NONE);
        }
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        // if (proxyProperties != null && proxyProperties.IsEnabled()) {
        // WifiManagerUtils.setWifiProxySettings(wifiPolicy, conf);
        // }
        int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        // TODO Make sure why disconnect and connect required here.
        // In current this is causing problem while sending job status to
        // server. Agent fails to send status because of network disconnect.
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        if (true) {
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        if (res == FAILED_TO_ADD_NETWORK) {
            // return false;
        } else {
            // return true;
        }
    }

    public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "* getScanResultSecurity");

        final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
        final String[] securityModes = { "WEP", "PSK", "EAP" };

        for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
                return securityModes[i];
            }
        }

        return "OPEN";
    }

    public static void setProxySettings(String assign,
            WifiConfiguration wifiConf) throws SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        setEnumField(wifiConf, assign, "proxySettings");
    }

    WifiConfiguration GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(WifiManager manager) {
        if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
            return null;

        List<WifiConfiguration> configurationList = manager
                .getConfiguredNetworks();
        WifiConfiguration configuration = null;
        int cur = manager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        for (int i = 0; i < configurationList.size(); ++i) {
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = configurationList.get(i);
            if (wifiConfiguration.networkId == cur)
                configuration = wifiConfiguration;
        }

        return configuration;
    }

    void setWifiProxySettings(WifiConfiguration config) {
        // get the current wifi configuration
        // WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        // WifiConfiguration config = GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(manager);
        if (null == config)
            return;

        try {
            // get the link properties from the wifi configuration
            Object linkProperties = getField(config, "linkProperties");
            if (null == linkProperties)
                return;

            // get the setHttpProxy method for LinkProperties
            Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class
                    .forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
            Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
            setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyPropertiesClass;
            Class lpClass = Class.forName("android.net.LinkProperties");
            Method setHttpProxy = lpClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy",
                    setHttpProxyParams);
            setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

            // get ProxyProperties constructor
            Class[] proxyPropertiesCtorParamTypes = new Class[3];
            proxyPropertiesCtorParamTypes[0] = String.class;
            proxyPropertiesCtorParamTypes[1] = int.class;
            proxyPropertiesCtorParamTypes[2] = String.class;

            Constructor proxyPropertiesCtor = proxyPropertiesClass
                    .getConstructor(proxyPropertiesCtorParamTypes);

            // create the parameters for the constructor
            Object[] proxyPropertiesCtorParams = new Object[3];
            proxyPropertiesCtorParams[0] = "127.0.0.1";
            proxyPropertiesCtorParams[1] = 8118;
            proxyPropertiesCtorParams[2] = "example.com";

            // create a new object using the params
            Object proxySettings = proxyPropertiesCtor
                    .newInstance(proxyPropertiesCtorParams);

            // pass the new object to setHttpProxy
            Object[] params = new Object[1];
            params[0] = proxySettings;
            setHttpProxy.invoke(linkProperties, params);

            setProxySettings("STATIC", config);

            // // save the settings
            // manager.updateNetwork(config);
            // manager.disconnect();
            // manager.reconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    void unsetWifiProxySettings() {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiConfiguration config = GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(manager);
        if (null == config)
            return;

        try {
            // get the link properties from the wifi configuration
            Object linkProperties = getField(config, "linkProperties");
            if (null == linkProperties)
                return;

            // get the setHttpProxy method for LinkProperties
            Class proxyPropertiesClass = Class
                    .forName("android.net.ProxyProperties");
            Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
            setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyPropertiesClass;
            Class lpClass = Class.forName("android.net.LinkProperties");
            Method setHttpProxy = lpClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy",
                    setHttpProxyParams);
            setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

            // pass null as the proxy
            Object[] params = new Object[1];
            params[0] = null;
            setHttpProxy.invoke(linkProperties, params);

            setProxySettings("NONE", config);

            // save the config
            manager.updateNetwork(config);
            manager.disconnect();
            manager.reconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

There are some extra code i have added apart from my previous answer so basically when this code runs successfully and when u navigate via browser anywhere this is output :

[image]

**EDIT : API FOR LOLLIPOP [the above api for proxy and ip wont work in latest Andriod L ]**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Implementation for Proxy setting for LOLLIPOP
            try {
                URL proxyUrl = new URL(
                        addNetworkProxyProperties.getHttpProxyUri());
                String host = proxyUrl.getHost();
                int portStr = proxyUrl.getPort();
                String exclusionList = addNetworkProxyProperties
                        .getExceptions();
                Constructor<ProxyInfo> constructor = ProxyInfo.class
                        .getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class, int.class,
                                String.class });
                ProxyInfo mHttpProxy = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {
                        host, portStr, exclusionList });
                Class ipConfigClass = Class
                        .forName("android.net.IpConfiguration");
                Object ipConfigObject = ipConfigClass.newInstance();
                Method setHttpProxy = ipConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setHttpProxy", ProxyInfo.class);
                setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);
                setHttpProxy.invoke(ipConfigObject, mHttpProxy);
                Method getHttpProxySettings = ipConfigClass
                        .getDeclaredMethod("getProxySettings");
                getHttpProxySettings.setAccessible(true);
                Method setProxy = config.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setProxy",
                        getHttpProxySettings.invoke(ipConfigObject).getClass(),
                        ProxyInfo.class);
                setProxy.setAccessible(true);
                setEnumField(ipConfigObject, "STATIC", "proxySettings");
                setProxy.invoke(config,
                        getHttpProxySettings.invoke(ipConfigObject), mHttpProxy);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /*
                 * Excepted exceptions may be SecurityException,
                 * IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
                 * InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException,
                 * InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException,
                 * NoSuchFieldException, MalformedURLException
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**NOTE in LOLLIPOP do chnage below statement for connecting the wifi :**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        conf.SSID = wifiName;
    } else {
        conf.SSID = Constants.BACKSLASH + wifiName + Constants.BACKSLASH;
    }
```

Comment: when I run the code on my htc one phone, its restart continuously!! I tried to turn off wifi and then the phone come backed to normal. what is that ? now I can't turn wifi on, when I do that the restarted and the same senario

Comment: when I turn off wifi and use forget network for the one I used to set setting, the problem solved. It seems some error occurred when the code try to set setting on connected wifi SSID, or atleast on my phone. can you say why this is happening ? I have 23 Hour to give the bounty  to your answer

Comment: code sets the fake ip hence making wifi in block state ,no need to restart the phone , you u can see code there are some random settings hard-caorded , plz note that things are hardcoded , to recover to hv to end up with just long press on wifi and do forget network , there is nothing much critical in code , just thing is you need to undertsand the code carefully or you will end up will complete mess...

Comment: my phone restarted by itself after I run the code and restart continuously after that. I Barely tried to turn off wifi because the phone restarted again after every load. I know about hardcode but couldn't find the Reason of restarting phone by itself, I think of some error on way the code set setting that make phone restarted by itself

Comment: i could not reproduce this restart stuff in my any of nexus version[nexus 12, nexus 13] , m not sure why is this so